# webscraping script for booking.com doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I made a script to scrape hotel name, rating and perks from hotels on this page : [link](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city&)

Here's my script :

```
import numpy as np


import time
from random import randint
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import random

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

url0 = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city&'
links1 = []

results = requests.get(url0, headers = headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

links1 = [a['href']  for a in soup.find("div", {"class": "hotellist sr_double_search"}).find_all('a', class_ = 'js-sr-hotel-link hotel_name_link url',  href=True)]
 

root_url = 'https://www.booking.com/'
urls1 = [ '{root}{i}'.format(root=root_url, i=i) for i in links1 ]



pointforts = []
hotels = []
notes = []

for url in urls1: 
    results = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    try :
        div = soup.find("div", {"class": "hp_desc_important_facilities clearfix hp_desc_important_facilities--bui"})
        pointfort = [x['data-name-en'] for x in div.select('div[class*="important_facility"]')]
        pointforts.append(pointfort)

    except:
        pointforts.append('Nan')

    try:    
        note = soup.find('div', class_ = 'bui-review-score__badge').text
        notes.append(note)

    except:
        notes.append('Nan')
    
    try:
        hotel = soup.find("h2",attrs={"id":"hp_hotel_name"}).text.strip("\n").split("\n")[1]
        hotels.append(hotel)
    except:
        hotels.append('Nan')



data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Notes' : notes,
    'Points fort' : pointforts,
    'Nom' : hotels})


#print(data.head(20))

data.to_csv('datatest.csv', sep=';', index=False, encoding = 'utf_8_sig')
```

It worked, I made a loop to scrape all the links for the hotel and after scrape ratings and perks for all of those hotels. But I had doublons, so instead of :
`links1 = [a['href']  for a in soup.find("div", {"class": "hotellist sr_double_search"}).find_all('a',  href=True)]`

I put :    `links1 = [a['href']  for a in soup.find("div", {"class": "hotellist sr_double_search"}).find_all('a', class_ = 'js-sr-hotel-link hotel_name_link url',  href=True)]` as you can see in my script above.

But now it doesn't work anymore, I obtained only `Nan`, while before, when I had doublons, I have some with Nan but most of them have the perks I wanted and the ratings. I don't understand why.

Here's the html for the hotels links :

[hotellink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFMGF.jpg)

Here's the html to get the name (after I obtaine the link, the script go to this link) :

[namehtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xwgD.jpg)

And here's the html to get all the perks related to the hotel (Like the name, the script go to the link I scraped before) :

[perkshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuGw0.png)

And here's my result...

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVrA9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` tags on that website contain newlines. One at the start and also some mid way through. As such when you try and combine `root_url` you are not getting valid URLs.

A fix can be to remove all the newlines. As the href always starts with a `/` this can also be removed from the `root_url`, or you could use [urllib.parse.urljoin()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urljoin#urllib.parse.urljoin).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

url0 = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city&'

results = requests.get(url0, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

links1 = [a['href'].replace('\n','')  for a in soup.find("div", {"class": "hotellist sr_double_search"}).find_all('a', class_ = 'js-sr-hotel-link hotel_name_link url',  href=True)]
root_url = 'https://www.booking.com'
urls1 = [f'{root_url}{i}' for i in links1]

pointforts = []
hotels = []
notes = []

for url in urls1: 
    results = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    try:
        div = soup.find("div", {"class": "hp_desc_important_facilities clearfix hp_desc_important_facilities--bui"})
        pointfort = [x['data-name-en'] for x in div.select('div[class*="important_facility"]')]
        pointforts.append(pointfort)
    except:
        pointforts.append('Nan')

    try:    
        note = soup.find('div', class_ = 'bui-review-score__badge').text
        notes.append(note)
    except:
        notes.append('Nan')
    
    try:
        hotel = soup.find("h2",attrs={"id":"hp_hotel_name"}).text.strip("\n").split("\n")[1]
        hotels.append(hotel)
    except:
        hotels.append('Nan')


data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Notes' : notes,
    'Points fort' : pointforts,
    'Nom' : hotels})

#print(data.head(20))
data.to_csv('datatest.csv', sep=';', index=False, encoding = 'utf_8_sig')
```

This would give you an output CSV file starting:

```
Notes;Points fort;Nom
 8,3 ;['Parking (fee required)', 'Free WiFi Internet Access Included', 'Family Rooms', 'Airport Shuttle', 'Non Smoking Rooms', '24 hour Front Desk', 'Bar'];Elysées Union
 8,4 ;['Free WiFi Internet Access Included', 'Family Rooms', 'Non Smoking Rooms', 'Pets allowed', '24 hour Front Desk', 'Rooms/Facilities for Disabled'];Hyatt Regency Paris Etoile
 8,3 ;['Free WiFi Internet Access Included', 'Family Rooms', 'Non Smoking Rooms', 'Pets allowed', 'Restaurant', '24 hour Front Desk', 'Bar'];Pullman Paris Tour Eiffel
 8,7 ;['Free WiFi Internet Access Included', 'Non Smoking Rooms', 'Restaurant', '24 hour Front Desk', 'Rooms/Facilities for Disabled', 'Elevator', 'Bar'];citizenM Paris Gare de Lyon
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! :) That was subtil, nicely done